# Why ReturnType is not working in this Swift function?

Tags: swift

**I am working with Swift 5, in Xcode 10.2.1**

I have this function inside of an extension of `UInt8`

The compiler complains in line 5, with **Unexpected non-void return value in void function**

The return type is properly defined, and if the line `return "\(opCode)"` is commented, it works fine, with the return in the last line `return "\(OpCode.NOP)`  I am using `"\(OpCode.NOP)"` to avoid adding another variable to the enum, but is a regular string

The error continues if I change the line to `return ""`, so it has nothing to do with the `OpCode` enum.

```
extension UInt8 {
    func opCode() -> String {
        OpCode.allCases.forEach { opCode in
            if self == opCode.uint8 {
                return "\(opCode)"  //Unexpected non-void return value in void function
                //return ""  // Error persists
            }
        }
        return "\(OpCode.NOP)"
    }
}
```

Comment: you can not return out of a closure. Rather pass the string to a variable outside the closure. and then don't use forEach but use a for loop instead.

Comment: Thx @arvidurs. I see it now

Comment: Unrelated, but: This seems like a violation of the single responsibility principle. `UInt8`'s job is to store numerical values, not to remember what op code it represents in some arbitrary architecture (and none others can be added). It's better to make a separate type for this.

Comment: Hi @Alexander. I have it with a typealias to Binary8.  I put UInt8 when posting the question to avoid confusion...  Now, after reading your comment, I think that it would be better to name the typealias OpCode = UInt8 and the string representation can be called mnemonic()

Comment: @eharo2 I don't even think a type alias is appropriate, because it's still fundamentally the same type (in that, anyone importing your code would have a strange `opCode()` method show up on every `UInt8`. In absence of a Haskell-like [`newtype`](http://tom.lokhorst.eu/2017/07/strongly-typed-identifiers-in-swift) feature, you should instead use a wrapper struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can't return a value inside void return type of the `forEach` instead try

```
extension UInt8 {
    func opCode() -> String { 
       if let item = OpCode.allCases.first(where:{ self == $0.uint8 }) { 
         return "\(item)"
       } 
        return "\(OpCode.NOP)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `return "\(OpCode.allCases.first(where:{ self == $0.uint8 }) ?? OpCode.NOP)"`